# How to move last name to the first?

Tags: javascript

I have names from a database in this format:

```
lastname mi firstname
```

And I'd like to change it to

```
firstname mi lastname
```

However, I keep getting a numeric value using the stuff Google has told me to do so far:

```
let s = 'lastname mi firstname'
let sa = s.split(' ')
let correctOrder = sa.unshift(sa.pop())  // 3
let correctOrder = sa.push(sa.shift());  // 3
```

What is the correct way to move firstname from the last position into the first?

Comment: What if one has two first names? I don't suggest doing anything about names. You just cannot control that by any programmatic means. Well, unless what you're doing is for learning purpose and has actually nothing to do with *people*.

Comment: ... and don't forget the classic [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) -- and [with examples](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So make it universal the task would be to swap the first and last words in a phrase.

The fastest solution would be to manipulate a string directly and slice it:

```js
const str = 'lastname mi mi2 firstname';

const firstIdx = str.indexOf(' '), lastIdx = str.lastIndexOf(' ');

console.log(str.slice(lastIdx + 1) + str.slice(firstIdx, lastIdx + 1) + str.slice(0, firstIdx));
```

The slower is swapping the first and last elements in an array:

```js
const str = 'lastname mi mi2 firstname';

const arr = str.split(' ');
// swap the first and last elements
[arr[arr.length - 1], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr.at(-1)];

console.log(arr.join(' '));
```

A regex solution is the most laconic but the slowest:

```js
const str = 'lastname mi mi2 firstname';

console.log(str.replace(/^(\w+)(.+?)(\w+)$/, '$3$2$1'));
```

And the benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="1000000">
const str = 'lastname mi firstname';

// @benchmark regex
str.replace(/^(\w+)(.+?)(\w+)$/, '$3$2$1');

// @benchmark split
const arr = str.split(' ');
// swap the first and last elements
[arr[arr.length - 1], arr[0]] = [arr[0], arr.at(-1)];
arr.join(' ');

// @benchmark string slice
const firstIdx = str.indexOf(' '), lastIdx = str.lastIndexOf(' ');
str.slice(lastIdx + 1) + str.slice(firstIdx, lastIdx + 1) + str.slice(0, firstIdx);

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: @TravisHeeter it's the same as swapping the first and last elements in a phrase. and my solution handles any number of words in the middle even 0. the first solution in my answer is the best imho. it's the fastest also. good for processing big arrays of users from backend for example

Comment: @TravisHeeter space-splitting into an array is slow...

Answer (score 0):

if there're only 3 words you could use [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
let s = 'lastname mi firstname'
let [s1,s2,s3] = s.split(' ');
let res = [s3,s2,s1].join(' ');
console.log(res)
```

**`regex`** approach:

```js
let s = 'lastname mi firstname';
let res = s.replace(/^(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)$/, '$3 $2 $1');
console.log(res);
```

Another approach using [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```js
let s = 'lastname mi firstname';
let res = s.match(/(\w+)/g).reverse().join(' ');
console.log(res);
```

with [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) and [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) methods:

```js
let s = 'lastname mi firstname';
let names = s.split(' ');
let res = [names.pop(), names.pop(), names.shift()].join(' ');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: How do you prevent "von Neumann John" (lastname 'von Neumann', no middle initial, firstname) from becoming "John Neumann von"? or even deal with anyone that has no middle initial, so only 2 words ... "Smith John"?

Comment: @StephenP check my universal solutions, looks better?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for ***most*** American names.

1. `.split(" ")` the string at every space: " " into an array of strings

   ```
    "last mi first".split(" ");
    // returns an array of strings: ["last", "mi", "first"]
   ```
2. Next `.reverse()` the array of strings

   ```
    ["last", "mi", "first"].reverse();
    // returns an array in reversed order: ["first", "mi", "last"]
   ```
3. Finally, `.join(" ")` the array of strings into a string with a space between the words

   ```
    ["first", "mi", "last"].join(" ");
    // returns a string with a space between words: "first mi last"
   ```

In the example below is a one-line function -- each Array method is chained.

```js
const fullName = "Christ H Jesus";

const fml = name => name.split(' ').reverse().join(' ');

console.log(fml(fullName));
```